# I am getting database error while triggering sql query within Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have the below code written in python. I am trying to execute simple read_sql and there seems to be no problem with respect to the sql and the connection. The SQL works perfectly fine when I independently run it in the sql server

```
    conn = odbc.connect ('Driver=SQL Server;'
                         'Server=xyz\CDEF;'
                         'Database =ABC;'
                         'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    sql = """select * from PQR 
        where AS_OF_DATE = '2020-01-21' and PORTFOLIO_NAME = 'TEST'"""
    ahv = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
```

Error

> ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in
>   execute(self, *args, **kwargs)    1399             else:
>   -> 1400                 cur.execute(*args)    1401             return cur
>
> ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'PQR'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 sql = """select * from PQR 
>         2     where AS_OF_DATE = '2020-01-21' and PORTFOLIO_NAME = 'TEST'"""
>   ----> 3 ahv = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in
>   read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates,
>   columns, chunksize)
>       379             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
>       380             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
>   --> 381             chunksize=chunksize)
>       382 
>       383     try:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in
>   read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates,
>   chunksize)    1433     1434         args = _convert_params(sql,
>   params)
>   -> 1435         cursor = self.execute(*args)    1436         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]    1437
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in
>   execute(self, *args, **kwargs)    1410             ex = DatabaseError(
>   1411                 "Execution failed on sql '%s': %s" % (args[0],
>   exc))
>   -> 1412             raise_with_traceback(ex)    1413     1414     @staticmethod
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat__init__.py
>   in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
>       401         if traceback == Ellipsis:
>       402             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
>   --> 403         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
>       404 else:
>       405     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in
>   execute(self, *args, **kwargs)    1398
>   cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)    1399             else:
>   -> 1400                 cur.execute(*args)    1401             return cur    1402         except Exception as exc:
>
> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from PQR 
>       where AS_OF_DATE = '2020-01-21' and PORTFOLIO_NAME = 'TEST'': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Invalid object name 'PQR'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Correct code does not usually fail with errors

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: Edited the body.

Comment: What do you get if you use `sql = "select db_name() as dbn"` ?

Comment: Hint: "Invalid object name" often means that you're not pointing to the database (catalog) that you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=localhost;uid=yourusername; pwd=yourpassword; Database = yourdatabase; Trusted_Connection=No;')
```

i guess you are making a mistake in pyodbc not odbc.
and try write driver object in curly braces {} and Trusted_Connection as No

Comment: No luck mate. My connection bit of query is successful and I am using 'import pyodbc as odbc'

Comment: try using double dots(.) as RISK..VW_ALL_HOLDINGS between DB name and table name

Comment: that doesn't help